# About the Spectrum of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I'm studying operator theory, and a doubt come at me, we know the diference between the pontual spectrum, the continuous spectrum and the residual spectrum. And we have that $\lambda \in \sigma(T)$ iff $T-\lambda I$ is not invertible. But the fact that $T-\lambda I$ is not invertible, implies that Ker($T-\lambda I$)$\neq 0$. But why this doesn't implies that $\lambda$ is in the point spectrum? And more, to show that some value $\lambda$ belongs to spectrum, usually the book find some sequence of points $x_{n}$ such that the norm of $(T-\lambda I$)$ x_{n}$ goes to zero. But why does this implie that the operator $T-\lambda I$) is not invertible?

Thank You!

Comment: "But the fact that $T−\lambda I$ is not invertible, implies that $\operatorname{Ker}(T−\lambda I)≠0$." No, the set-theoretic inverse of $T - \lambda I$ need not be continuous. "Invertible" means the inverse is a continuous operator.

Comment: And even if the kernel is trivial, the the operator might not be surjective, and then it doesn't have an inverse function, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an infinite-dimensional Banach space $E$, it is no longer true that for an operator $S:E\to E$, 
$$\text{$S$ is not invertible}\implies\ker(S)\text{ is non-trivial}.$$
It may help to read [the Wikipedia article on the decomposition of the spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_of_spectrum_%28functional_analysis%29#Definitions).